# Where did the jewelry go?

Tags: plot-explanation, robot-and-frank

In the movie "Robot and Frank," Frank steals valuable jewelry with the help of a household robot. He hides the loot well enough that the police can not find it and he escapes punishment. At the end of the movie, he passes a note to his son saying that the jewelry was buried in a garden, but the son clearly does not take this seriously, though he knows his father was a thief. Presumably, the son believes that the father, whose dementia was well established by this point in the movie, does not know where the jewelry is. It was, after all, hidden by a robot whose memory was later wiped.

So, where is the loot? Was there some explicit clue earlier in the movie that I missed?

Comment: Why do you doubt the note? As far as I remember, the note saying that the jewelry was buried under the tomato plants is pretty much the only location given.

Comment: Frank has shown profound memory loss and confusion through the entire film, including just before the passing of the note when he asked his son how he was liking Princeton, a college from which the son had graduated fifteen years earlier. Why should we believe he has the location of the jewels right? The way I read the son's response is "the old man's got another pointless guess about what happened to the loot."

Comment: That's true. However Franks usually seems coherent when dealing with things concerning being a burglar. Also, I've had family members who had Alzheimer's (and dementia is similar - Frank could have had either one) and they often have times of brief clarity. At any rate, I believe that was the only mention of where the jewelry was so I don't believe there was some "explicit clue" that you missed.

Answer (score 1):

The loot is in the garden under the tomatoes. Setting aside Frank's memory issues, this is the end of the garden thread that is introduced early on in the movie. Robot tries to help his patient in becoming more active by taking up a hobby such as gardening. We get to see repeated scenes of Robot preparing a garden and planting tomatoes. It is a minor thread that is tied off at the end with a bit of reveal.

Comment: +1 It might not be the most elaborate answer, but it's correct. In order to make something believable, screenwriters are taught to introduce it ("set it up") early to be able to use that later on to, for example, let the hero defeat the antagonist ("pay off"). It's been a while since I watched the movie, but, something that's referenced and shown as early, and as many times as the garden is, is definitely set-up. And, if I remember correctly, it's not payed off in any other way, so, whether it's clear or not in the movie, it's definitely where the jewelry is hidden.